# Multi-dimensional Gaussian integral with linear term

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am recently working on a problem of multi-dimensional Gaussian integral with linear term. The formula is
$$\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}A_{ij} x_i x_j+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}B_i x_i} d^nx=\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^T {A} \vec{x}+\vec{B}^T \vec{x}} d^nx= \sqrt{ \frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det{A}} }e^{\frac{1}{2}\vec{B}^{T}{A}^{-1}\vec{B}}.$$
In my case, $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. I worked out the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and eigenfunctions of matrix $A$. So I can calculate the determinant of $A$ as $$\det{A} = \prod \lambda_n.$$
The problem is how do I calculate $\vec{B}^{T}{A}^{-1}\vec{B}$ with the eigenvalues of $A$. Here we assume $\vec{B}$ is the simplest constant vector
$ \vec{B} = (b, b, b, \cdots, b)^{T}$.

Maybe it is a simple question and I am just so stupid to come up with a solution. Anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The vector $B=(B_1,B_2,....B_n)$, not a constant b.

Answer (score 1):

Put the eigenvectors of $\mathbf A $ into a matrix which you call $\mathbf U$, and denote the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues $\mathbf \Lambda$. Then

$$
\mathbf B^T \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf B = \\
 \mathbf B^T \mathbf (\mathbf U^T \mathbf \Lambda \mathbf U)^{-1} \mathbf B = \\
 \mathbf B^T \mathbf U^T \mathbf \Lambda^{-1} \mathbf U \mathbf B 
$$

So you calculate the vector $\mathbf V = \mathbf U \mathbf B $ which is the decomposition of the vector $\mathbf B $ into eigendirections of $\mathbf A $. Then you have

$$
\mathbf B^T \mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf B = 
 \mathbf V^T \mathbf \Lambda^{-1} \mathbf V = 
\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 / \lambda_i
$$

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.